# RabbitTemplate not returning the message back to caller

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have project microservice where I have restful call which calls the endpoint in Service microservice.

Currently I have a problem where Service return the message back to API in the middle RabbitTemplate's method handleDelivery() not able to pass on the message to the caller back in the restful program. I.e. the message is disappearing somewhere never returns back.

So I am stuck and not able to proceed with this.
How do I fix/over come this problem.

Your help is highly appreciated.

thank you.
~Shyam

Comment: Please, provide more background regarding your architecture and share a Spring config for AMQP and the code where you are doubting. And maybe there is some StackTrace on the matter... Otherwise it's difficult to be Oracle to predict the root of cause. What I can say that `sendAndReceive` requires that the other side will reply t othe proper `replyTo` header to get a response back.

Comment: Thanks a lot Artem Bilan for your reply, Unforunately there is not much trace available in logs.

Comment: But I have something snippet where it is disappearing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Artem Bilan for your reply, Unforunately there is not much trace available in logs. But I have something i.e. snippet to share where exactly it is disappering ...

Comment: RabbitTemplate.class

Message reply = new Message(body, messageProperties);
                                         if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                                                logger.trace("Message received " + reply);
                                         }
                                         try {
                                                replyHandoff.put(reply);
                                         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

Comment: The message is coming back till Message reply = new Message(body, messageProperties); But disappearing inside if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                                                logger.trace("Message received " + reply);
                                         }
the control never came back from this line ...if it returns retunrs a null message. This RabbitTemplate.class is of "spring-rabbit-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar" .   Let me know if any further info is needed.....thank u ~Shyam

Comment: One more observation Artem, In my service i have a code to create a new queue name in the configuration file if it does not already exists. But whereas in this case new queue is been created with the name "amq.gen-QPwpOm9Rs3IHYZCZEb7Bcw" but it does not hold any payload. moreover when I try to delete it , it wont let me delete. I am not sure what is going on ? Can you plz help me.

Comment: Mean while I found one more thing , my service returns i.e. pushes a JSON string into queue , this is JSON string is the records retrieved from the database, till 7K records it is working fine. beyond that it is not able to handle....hope this helps you to narrow down the problem. Plz share your expert advice to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please, edit your question and all these info there: such a long text isn't readable from comments.